# I have a problem with packing my maven selenium project in a standalone jar-file. There is no cp for testclasses despite being in jar file

Tags: selenium, maven, jar, classpath, uberjar

I try to pack my maven selenium autotest project into a standalone jar. I use the next main class to start test classes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
    request.setPomFile(new File("pom.xml"));
    request.setGoals(Collections.singletonList("install"));
    Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
    invoker.setMavenHome(new File(System.getenv("MAVEN_HOME")));
    try {
        invoker.execute(request);
    } catch (MavenInvocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have no problem with this, the tests are perfectly running from the mainclass. The next step is to pack the project into a jar-file. So I use maven-jar-plugin and maven-assembly-plugin for that purpose:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>common.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/test/resources/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

and my assembly:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>test-jar-with-dependencies</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <!-- we're creating the test-jar as an attachement -->
            <useProjectAttachments>true</useProjectAttachments>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.class</include>
            </includes>
            <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

I manage to pack both common and test classes in a jar-file. I manually put the pom file and the testing file in the same directory as the jar file, so I have no trouble with starting the project. But the tests don't run, because the test-classes are not found, despite being inside the project.

I will be very appreciative if anyone gives me a clue about what I do wrong.

P.S. I put here a refer to my project: https://bitbucket.org/Max1203/donatiton-script.git

Answer (score 0):

Test class not found may be  misconfiguration
Can you reimport maven dependencies it will solve

Maven cycle-Reload All maven projects

Comment: Thank you for answering! If I got you right you meant to reload the maven project and then build a jar file again. I did so but unfortunately, the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody needs the answer. Just change the code in MainClass to the next one:

```
TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
        testNG.setTestSuites(Arrays.asList("testng.xml"));
        testNG.setPreserveOrder(true);
        testNG.run();
```

It is gonna solve the problem.